# Onmiauth-Facebook not saving facebook_id to users table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I've ran bundle exec rake db:migrate and have 2 databases. I'm also using SQLite in development. 
I get the following error when I go to http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook:

`You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]`

It points to this code in app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `create'
:

```
    def create
      auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

      @authorization = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
      if @authorization
        render :text => "Welcome back #{@authorization.user.name}! You have already signed up."
      else
######line 12->  user = User.new :name => auth_hash["user_info"]["name"], :email => auth_hash["user_info"]["email"]
        user.authorizations.build :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"]
        user.save

        render :text => "Hi #{user.name}! You've signed up."
      end
    end
```

I think this means that my array of info is empty, and narrows me down to this reasoning that data is not being saved onto my database.

Btw, I'm on step 6 following http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I just got this working by downloading the source app from that site and fixing some stuff and putting in my own app keys, etc. Not sure what the actual deal is with the tutorial, but tweaking the example app worked for me.

Comment: Thanks John. I appreciate the feedback and solution. I haven't gotten it to work since I've been quite busy, but I've found several strange things such as Facebook's user info hash not including certain variables in an organized manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I think I see where this example went awry. The example that is being used in the above site is using the previous version of omniauth, which used "user_info" as the name of the hash. The new 1.0 version of omniauth changed that name to just "info" and split the provider strategies into separate gems, so you have to specify them separately in your Gemfile (ex: omniauth-facebook, omniauth-twitter, etc). So you don't use the just plain 'omniauth' gem in the Gemfile anymore.

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Upgrading-to-1.0